# Build observable JavaFX-Beans

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm currently developing an hierarchical data structure. In fact it's a tree. Instead of using JavaBeans I thought of using the JavaFX-Bean/Property-Framework as I like it's new more modern approach.

But I stumbled in a problem: As said before, I have an hierarchical data structure. Imagine a leaf having changed its name. Of course the GUI, listening to this explicit SimpleStringProperty notices the change. But besides the GUI I also have business logic which has to react to any name-change ocurring in my tree-data-structure. 
As I don't want to register my business logic to every element in the tree, I want the tree to pass events up to the root element.

So in old JavaBeans every bean had a PropertyChangeSupport; every parent node could listen to it's children, rethrow the event, problem solved. But in JavaFX I simply can't find a similar solution.

Is there somewhere an "ObservableBean" superclass? (Well obviously there isn't as I already searched for it, but maybe anyone knows how to solve my problem anyway without reinventing the weel).

Comment: One solution is to have a way of referencing the root node from each child (`getRoot`, which is calls `getRoot` from the parent), and then add common  root's listener to all the children nodes.